# How to display total amount on the order edit page woocamerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code to display field order total amount on the order edit page:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){

    $method = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_payment_method', true );
    if($method != 'pec_gateway_check')
        return;

    echo date('Y/m/d', strtotime("+40 days")) . " تاریخ چک صیادی";
}
```

I want add below code to show total amount in this page:
How to do that?

```
  global $woocommerce;
  $carttotal = $woocommerce->cart->total;
  $total35 = $carttotal*0.35;
  $total65 = $carttotal*0.65;

    echo number_format($total35) . " ریال پرداخت شده";
    echo number_format($total65) . " ریال مبلغ چک پرداختی";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, it sounds like you just need to add the code you've written to the function you already have.  So something like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    global $woocommerce;

    $method = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_payment_method', true );
    if($method != 'pec_gateway_check')
        return;

    echo date('Y/m/d', strtotime("+40 days")) . " تاریخ چک صیادی";

    $carttotal = $woocommerce->cart->total;
    $total35 = $carttotal*0.35;
    $total65 = $carttotal*0.65;

    echo number_format($total35) . " ریال پرداخت شده";
    echo number_format($total65) . " ریال مبلغ چک پرداختی";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this code echo "0" on the order edit page. how can i show cart total in this page?

Comment: I would try first echoing the contents of `$carttotal`.  It's possible they multiplication you're doing doesn't work (maybe a currency symbol?).  Otherwise you could try replacing `$woocommerce->cart->total;` with `WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();`

Comment: In '$carttotal' we only have number output and elsewhere it has worked for us.
By replacing your code, the order edit page will not load.

Comment: I try replacing this. it has worked:  $order->get_total();